# Service Block with zero queue capacity

Tags: service, queue, block, anylogic, capacity

I am trying to model a production line where the workstation has only 1 max capacity. I used "Service" block to model seize-delay-release. However, since the resource is available to let more than one "agent" flow into this service block, it creates a mis-understanding. As shown below, the "Base 1" block has 2 agents - 1 at seize queue, 1 at delay which is wrong, should be just 1 at delay. How can I solve it as I can't put "zero" at Queue capacity.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4I1H.jpg)

Comment: If more than one agent arrives, where would you want to have the extra agents wait? Even if you remove the queue, your agents beyond the 1 capacity have to wait somewhere, so what are you planning to do with those?

Comment: there is an additional queue in the front of the production line at start for storage, then for the rest of the line, the agent stays at the workstation until the next one is available.

Comment: I am thinking to use restricted area

Comment: Restricted area is what I wanted to suggest, but you would still need a queue before the restricted area block. That is why I asked you first the question.

Comment: yes in my case, there is no buffer area within the production line thus can't have a queue

Comment: So guess you answered yourself 

Comment: Yes I am going to try now, thanks!

Comment: why is the queue before **Service** needed? why not just use **Service**'s own queue to store entities until resources become available?

Comment: Yes the queue I've mentioned is the Service Block's own queue.